# RabbitMQ - "user" trying to log in after user was deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rabbitmq, amazon-eks

After deploying RabbitMQ in k8s with helm [chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq-cluster-operator), I deleted user called **user** through management console and also added new definitions. The pod started constantly crashing/restarting and logs started showing multiple:

```
2023-07-07 21:15:37.942748+00:00 [warning] <0.1146.0> HTTP access denied: user 'user' - invalid credentials
2023-07-07 21:15:40.797249+00:00 [info] <0.1236.0> RabbitMQ is asked to stop...
```

I double checked, and there is no user **user**.

Why is it logging this out if **user** is no longer present and why is pod crashing because if this?

Answer (score 0):

The liveness probe was using this command so pod was failing

```
exec [sh -ec curl -f --user user:$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD 127.0.0.1:15672/api/health/checks/virtual-hosts]
```